# configure custom attributes in AAD for Saas Applications

Tags: salesforce, azure-active-directory, scim

I'm currently trying to configure Azure Ad for user provisioning in a Salesforce Sandbox. I'm using a personal dev org and a trial Azure account to make this work.

I've been able to map attributes and it works for most of them, except one. ManagerID.

I'm trying to replicate the Azure AD manager information into Salesforce's managerID field using an attribute reference. However it doesn't seem to work.

Has anyone here been completing this kind of setup previously and would be able to point me to the correct Attribute expression to be mapped/referenced on the Azure AD side?

- The default mapping is from Salesforce->ManagerId to AAD->Manager, where AAD-> Manager is a reference to User.
- The field in Salesforce used for matching is the FederationIdentifier, which corresponds to AAD-> User.userPrincipalName

The logic would be that if I'm doing a reference to the AAD User, I would expect AAD to fetch that manager's UPN in AAD and pass it back to the SCIM interface to be able to match it on the Salesforce side (since it's mapped to the FederationIdentifier).

I'm also trying to force the reference of "Manager" on the AAD side to pick the User.UserPrincipalName but it seems to always bring it back to User.

Anyhow, I'm a bit fishing here and wondering if there is someone with whom I can share the settings in such way that I can compare how it's been done in a successful implementation.

Comment: I found in Identity Connect 2.1.0 Implementation Guide that by default, the manager attribute in Active Directory is mapped to the managerID attribute in Salesforce, using a transformation script. The transformation script locates the Active Directory manager property and looks up the manager's objectGUID, based on the value of his distinguishedName. The script then locates the corresponding SalesforceID of the manager, in the links table, and uses this ID to populate the managerID property in Salesforce.

Comment: May be this information will help you in your above implementation.